# What's the probability distribution for this problem?

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

In my city there is a bus stop, during 6:30pm to 7pm there is a scheduled bus,
the time it arrives the stop is random but it always comes in this time range, what
will be the probability distribution when the random variable is the time?
I have two contradicted pictures in my mind: it's uniform distribution since the probability that the bus come in every minute is equal; it's some other distribution since the probability that the bus comes is higher and higher in later time of 6:30-7pm if the bus haven't come in previous time range.

Comment: You say "*it's uniform distribution since the probability that the bus come in every minute is equal*" but that information was not present in the question statement.  Where did that assumption come from?  Is it a valid assumption?  As it is currently written using only the information in the question-statement there is not enough information to determine a distribution uniquely and it could well have been a distribution different than the uniform one.

Comment: That is NOT a valid assumption, it's only my guess since the bus could come in any minute.

Comment: "*If I assume the answer to the question is $A$, then the answer is $A$*"... if you assume the distribution is uniform (*i.e. if you assume probability that the bus come in every minute is equal*) then the distribution is uniform... but that is wholly uninteresting and circular.  It is far more common in real life for wait times to be closer to being normally distributed, with arrival times far more concentrated around the mean.

Comment: In fact, to better adhere to bus schedules, in real life if a bus is running ahead of time they will often wait at a stop until their software tells them it is time to go again, making it far less likely that they arrive considerably early to the next stop.  The end result again is that you have far too little information here to be able to say anything with certainty.  (*Source: I rode public transit for several years and saw exactly this happen*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your two "contradicting" images are actually not contradicting. They are just answers to two different questions.

Pay close attention to your own words: *the probability that the bus comes is higher and higher in later time of 6:30-7pm **if the bus haven't come in previous time range**.* You are talking about conditional distributions here.

Let's suppose that the distribution is (originally) uniform over the 30 minutes, so if you go to the bus stop at 6:30, you think that there is $1/30$ chance that it arrives during the first minute, $1/30$ for the next and so on, up to $1/30$ chance that it will arrive during the last minute. Adding up you have $30 \cdot (1/30) = 1$ probability = certainty that it will arrive before 7:00.

Now **if** you have waited for 20 minutes and the bus did not come, **then** you know that this time it will be in the remaining 10-minute range. The conditional distribution is uniform over the remaining range. You have $1/10$ chance that it will arrive during the next minute. Remember: This is because now you **know** it did not arrive between 6:00 - 6:20. Originally you did not know that.

**If** you have waited for 29 minutes and the bus has not come, you are **certain** (probability = 1) it will arrive during the last minute. Originally you had just $1/30$ chance that it would be during the last minute. Two different probabilities because one is unconditional and the other is conditional.

**If** you have waited for 29 minutes and 59 seconds, and the bus did not come, you are certain it will arrive during the next second. (If your assumptions are valid.)

Comment: That's very clear explanation. If the setting changes to "On average people wait for 10 mins for a bus", from what I read the probability distribution for the waiting time is exponential distribution, but I have hard time to understand that the first minute have higher probability that later time. It seems to me the exponential distribution has encoded the condition that the bus haven't come in the previous minute into it.

Comment: What's the distribution in above setting and why?

Comment: If the original distribution of arrival time $X$ (in minutes after 6:30) is $\text{Unif}(0,30)$ and you have waited $T$ minutes without seeing the bus, then the conditional distribution is $\text{Unif}(T,30)$. You'll notice that its density $1/(30-T)$ gets higher and higher as $T$ increases. To address the "why": Calculate the conditional probabilities $P(X < c \;|\; X>T)$, to get the conditional CDF, and take the derivative to get the conditional PDF.

Comment: "Above setting" I meant "On average bus comes 1 per 10 mins", but not fixed as 1 must come in each 10 mins.

Comment: Sounds like a Poisson process, where the waiting time for the next bus is exponentially distributed.

Comment: That's what I guessed; Exponential distribution is memoryless, does it mean every minute has the same probability? The distribution function shows the first minute has higher than the second minute. So it doesn't mean that. My guess is that the random variable is time, so the event happens in the second minute's probability is a conditional probability and that's why it's lower.  What does this memoryless property mean? Could you give an concrete example?

Comment: You still need to keep in mind the distinction between unconditional and conditional distribution. If the original (unconditional) distribution is exponential, its density is decreasing as time increases. But on the condition that $X\ge t$, the conditional density at $t$ is the same as the unconditional density was at $0$. I believe you are still confusing the density function with the hazard function, so check that out (Wikipedia or otherwise).

Comment: If the (original) distribution is uniform, its density is constant but the hazard function is increasing as time passes.  If the (original) distribution is exponential, is density is decreasing but the hazard function is constant as time passes.  It is very easy to confuse these with each other.